# Is it a bad idea to use Rhino.Commons unitofwork and repository?

Tags: nhibernate

Seems the project is not active anymore. Or am I missing something? Is there any other unitorwork/repository implementations for nhibernate?

Comment: Ayende is making many anti-repository blog posts now so I wouldn't expect many updates going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Craig said, Ayende is pretty much against the repository pattern (and by extension somewhat, the unit of work pattern) now. See:

- [Repository is the new singleton](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)
- [The wages of sin: Proper and improper usage of abstracting an OR/M](http://ayende.com/blog/4788/the-wages-of-sin-proper-and-improper-usage-of-abstracting-an-or-m)
- [Architecting in the pit of doom: The evils of the repository abstraction layer](http://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer)
- [Ask Ayende: Life without repositories, are they worth living?](http://ayende.com/blog/153701/ask-ayende-life-without-repositories-are-they-worth-living)

And there are plenty more where that lot came from.

The basic underlying premise is, he believes that NHibernate is already enough of an abstraction over the database so you don't need another layer. On top of that, by abstract NHibernate, you're doing yourself a diservice with regard to the powerful features that NHibernate provides.

Based on this new attitude, I would imagine that the repository and unit of work stuff in Rhino will be left alone now.